# Help in ERP project in windows form

Tags: c#

I want to download some of ERP projects source code based on windows form, to understand their coding structure, and designing, so that I could be able to develop ERP project.

Could anyone please tell where I can find some of free ERP projects source code?

Comment: windows form? do you mean Developer 2K?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ERP_software_packages).  No winforms, java rules in that world.  Doesn't matter, ERP has little to do with user interface programming.

Answer (score 1):

Although Hans is right when stating it's mostly Java, there actually are some .net initiatives in this field on Codeplex, see   http://www.google.nl/search?q=codeplex+erp. I have no experience with those and would advice you look at the more mature projects in the list provided by Hans. I like opentaps (Java) and openerp (python).